# Extract key, value from columns field in Postgresql table

Tags: json, postgresql

```
 id   |                   columns                    |         timestamp          | query_id             |               task_id
-------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------+----------------------+---------------------------
     1 | {"uid": "112", "name": "redis-server"}       | 2018-07-18 18:45:39.045387 |                    1 |                         2
     2 | {"uid": "0", "name": "celery"}                 | 2018-07-18 18:45:39.047671 |                    1 |                         2
     3 | {"uid": "111", "name": "post"}           | 2018-07-18 18:45:39.048218 |                    1 |                         2
     4 | {"uid": "111", "name": "post"}           | 2018-07-18 18:45:39.048732 |                    1 |                         2
```

Looking to extract normal values from json for UID & NAME through query syntax

Comment: [JSON Functions and Operators.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON operator ->>. ie:

```
select *, "columns"->>'uid' as uid, "columns"->>'name' as name
from myTable;
```

Comment: Thanks very much Cetin, i tried this and it added the two new columns UID and NAME , the other thing left is need to remove original COLUMNS as well,

Comment: @harman, then simply list the columns you want in result list instead of * .

Comment: Hi @cetin, is there a efficient way to extract it by script as i will be having more than hundred fieldsets to make them as extracted column.

Comment: @harman, not one I know of. You might check https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151838/postgresql-json-column-to-view for an indirect solution. And if your question is answered please don't forget the mark the answer.